# MoveIt: Octomap + Collision + Trajectory = Octomap being ignored!

Tags: ros, moveit, collision, octomap, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community!

Im currently working on a setup with MoveIt and an octomap being updated constantly, which works just fine, but now I need the robot to avoid the octomap points during planning and I just cant achieve it!
The only way I've found so far to display the octomap was to download a Octomap Server, update it with PointCloud2 info and add the PointCloud2 Display at MoveIt, setting its topic to /octomap_point_cloud_centers. This visualization also works just fine, but how am I supposed to take octomap points into account when planning a trajectory? Those octomap points are just being ignored!
Is there a way to display the Octomap with MotionPlanning or PlanningScene? How?

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide to make my problem clearer!

Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143741/moveit:-octomap-+-collision-+-trajectory-=-octomap-being-ignored!/) by [Thrmotta](https://answers.ros.org/users/13786/thrmotta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In arm navigation there was a simple setting in the launch file: `use_collision_map` if set to false the map was competently ignored. Perhaps there is a similar setting in MoveIt.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1